# How to parametrize prepared data

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I need to prepare an entity with suitable child entities.  I need to specify the type of entities that will be stored in the prepared parent entity. Like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(element_types)
def entry_type_id(element_types)
    elements = [resolve_elements_create(data=element_data(element_type)) for element_type in element_types]
    entry_type_id = resolve_entry_type_create(elements)
    
    return entry_type_id



 def test_something(entry_type_id([ElementType1, ElementType2])):
       ...
```

I can't create one fixture for each use case, because there are so many combinations I need. Is there any way I can pass parameters to the ficture to customize the prepared entity?

Comment: I'm not familiar with fixtures, but according [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#what-fixtures-are) fixture should be initialized at `Arrange` step. In your case fixture can be determined only at `Act` step. What is profit of `fixture` using? Just use `entry_type_id` as usual function with parameters inside test

Comment: @rzlvmp Yes, thank you. For some reason, I thought that the use of functions is not correct in the case of tests. Write this as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Did you mean using paramterize with indirect=True? 
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html

Comment: @R.K, No, this is a parameterization of the test. And I needed to parameterize the data, before the test.  For example: I need to test deleting something, so I need entity that will deleted before test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you end point is but according to your comment I think you should create a test class so you can create the elements and then delete them, since you want to test the creation + deletion of the entries

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def entry_type(request)
    element = resolve_elements_create(data=element_data(request.param))
    # This should return 0 if Error during creation
    return resolve_entry_type_create(element)
```

following by the test it self

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("entry_type", [ElementType1, ElementType2], indirect=True)
class TestEntries:
   def test_create_entry(entry_type):
     assert entry_type

   def test_delete_entry(entry_type):
     assert delete_entry(entry_type)
```

This is more of a psuedo code it will need some changes, but in most cases the use of fixtures should be prefered over functions in pytest.